# How to disable spring security authentication in grails for a particular url, using grails 2.2.5

Tags: grails, spring-security

How to disable authentication in Grails spring security for a particular URL.
So that without entering any username/password, i can access the URL.
Currently am using interceptUrlMap in config.groovy, and am applying as below

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "interceptUrlMap "

grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
   '/particularurl/**':  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/**'             :         ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

I want to access the /particularurl/** straight away bypassing the spring security.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
'/particularurl/**' : ['permitAll']
```

Read more: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/requestMappings.html

Comment: Remember to restart your server